# Getting last row of each group in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as following:

**messages**

```
+----+--------+-----------------+
| id | sender | body            |
+----+--------+-----------------+
| 11 | 4      | test msg one    |
| 12 | 4      | test msg        |
| 13 | 1      | this is test    |
| 14 | 4      | WANT TO SHOW G1 |
| 15 | 4      | WANT TO SHOW G2 |
+----+--------+-----------------+
```

**message_receivers**

```
+----------+------------+
| receiver | message_id |
+----------+------------+
| 1        |         11 |
| 1        |         12 |
| 4        |         13 |
| 1        |         14 |
| 3        |         15 |
+----------+------------+
```

I have written following query

```
SELECT 
    `messages`.`id`,
    `messages`.`body` ,
    `messages`.`sender`, 
    MAX(`messages`.`id`) AS MID,
    IF(`messages`.`sender`>`message_receivers`.`receiver`,`CONCAT_WS`(',',`messages`.`sender`,`message_receivers`.`receiver`), 

`CONCAT_WS`(',',`message_receivers`.`receiver`,`messages`.`sender`)) AS `conc`
FROM
    `messages`
JOIN `message_receivers` ON `messages`.`id` = `message_receivers`.`message_id`
WHERE 
    `message_receivers`.`receiver` = '4' 
    OR `messages`.`sender` = '4'
GROUP BY conc
```

which give me the following result

```
+----+-----------------+--------+------+------+
| id | body            | sender | MID  | conc |
+----+-----------------+--------+------+------+
| 11 | test msg one    | 4      |   14 | 4,1  |
| 15 | WANT TO SHOW G2 | 4      |   15 | 4,3  |
+----+-----------------+--------+------+------+
```

But I want

```
+----+-----------------+--------+------+------+
| id | body            | sender | MID  | conc |
+----+-----------------+--------+------+------+
| 14 | WANT TO SHOW G1 | 4      |   14 | 4,1  |
| 15 | WANT TO SHOW G2 | 4      |   15 | 4,3  |
+----+-----------------+--------+------+------+
```

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you are getting non grouped by columns. You get the max message id and the body, but there is no reason why these should be from the same row.

Comment: Because i need to get same thread's latest message..

Comment: Yes, but your query does not do that. The fields you return are not for the max message. You get the max message id, but the other message fields will be from an undefined matching record. For example, if you had a simple SELECT message_id, MIN(receiver) FROM message_receivers query the min receiver would be 1, but the message id might be any of 11, 12 or 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a sub query to get the max message, and then joining that back to get the other fields:-

```
SELECT messages.id, messages.body, messages.sender, Sub1.MID, Sub1.conc
FROM messages
INNER JOIN message_receivers 
ON messages.id = message_receivers.message_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        IF(messages.sender>message_receivers.receiver,
            CONCAT_WS(',',messages.sender,message_receivers.receiver), 
            CONCAT_WS(',',message_receivers.receiver,messages.sender)) AS conc,
        MAX(messages.id) AS MID
    FROM messages
    JOIN message_receivers 
    ON messages.id = message_receivers.message_id
    WHERE message_receivers.receiver = '4' 
    OR messages.sender = '4'
    GROUP BY conc
) Sub1
ON Sub1.MID = messages.id
AND Sub1.conc = IF(messages.sender>message_receivers.receiver,
            CONCAT_WS(',',messages.sender,message_receivers.receiver), 
            CONCAT_WS(',',message_receivers.receiver,messages.sender))
```

SQL fiddle for it - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ee98/2

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution is to use an uncorrelated subquery, as follows:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT grouping_column
            , MAX(ordering_column) max_ordering_column 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY grouping_column
     ) y
    ON y.grouping_column = x.grouping_column
   AND y.max_ordering_column = x.ordering_column;
```

or, where a key is formed on multiple columns...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT grouping_column1
            , grouping_column2
            , MAX(ordering_column) max_ordering_column 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY grouping_column1
            , grouping_coulmn2
     ) y
    ON y.grouping_column1 = x.grouping_column1
   AND y.grouping_column2 = x.grouping_column2
   AND y.max_ordering_column = x.ordering_column;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution but my problem is my grouping_column is a concatenate column.

Comment: No it's not. It's just two columns instead of one.